# ASP.NET Web Architecture Design

Tags: asp.net, architecture, web-applications

The problem I'm having with writing a web application architecture is that I want separate components that work together.  By this I simply mean, for example, a navigation bar and the actual page content (as well as a header, which is static) in ASP.NET.

Now, here's where it gets interesting:

- There are no two pages the same
- The navigation pages on every page have security on them on a user-by-user basis
- The navigation has links to other locations

The problem I'm mainly having is that you've usually got to have a full web page in Visual Studio, and if you have portions i.e. excluding your <html> tags then Visual Studio will end up underlining everything as incorrect.

The way is this application is currently being dealt with is using frames (yes, frames) to keep everything separate, but working together.  I want to move away from this, although the web system is very large, and very important in that it must be available 24/7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at Master Pages in ASP.NET 2.0? These can be used in conjunction with User Controls, and the [Site Map Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx).

- [Master Pages Quickstart Tutorial](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/masterpages/default.aspx)
- [MSDN Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)
- [Master Pages: Tips, Tricks, and Traps](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)
- [Example Template Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336603.aspx)

Comment: They're a bit more than a simple template.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to implement UserControls for this? for example a navigation user control that can handle the security for itself etc etc.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good book you should check out that might shed some light on your problem. It's "ASP.NET 2.0 Website Programming: Problem - Design - Solution", part of the Wrox series.